# .Net framework 2.0 Configuration Tool

Tags: .net, frameworks

I recently installed windows 7, visual studio 2008, and .net framework 3.5.

With these installed, I was unable to find the .net framework configuration tool.

It should be located in  %windir%\Microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.507727\ with the file name  mscorcfg.msc

The only place I found something similar is in  %windir%\Microsoft.net\framework\v1.0.3705 where there are files named mscormmc.cfg and mscormmc.dll

Any idea where to get the configuration tool?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is included in [.NET 2.0 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fe6f2099-b7b4-4f47-a244-c96d69c35dec&displaylang=en). You need to install the SDK to get it.

ADDITION: Here is a separate link for the [.NET 2.0 SDK (64 bit version)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=1aef6fce-6e06-4b66-afe4-9aad3c835d3d&displayLang=en) for use on 64-bit machines.