# Running a C# exe file

Tags: c#, .net

#### Duplicate:

> [Why does my .NET application crash when run from a network drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148879/why-does-my-net-application-crash-when-run-from-a-network-drive)

---

Can someone help me?  For a school project, I wrote a C# windows application in Visual Studio 2005.  It works just fine, no problems.  I want to be able to share this program with others in my department at work.  So, I copied the exe file to a network drive.  When we attempt to run the exe from the network, it fails with "name of progrm...has encountered a problem and needs to close".  If I have the co-worker copy the exe file to their c:\ drive then attempt to run, it works.  Why won't my program run from the network drive?

Susan

Answer (score 14):

.NET by default does not allow applications to be run off a network drive. Either copy it to a local drive or alter the security settings for .NET.

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148879/why-does-my-net-application-crash-when-run-from-a-network-drive) should give you what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has finally realised that the default behavior of preventing applications from running off a network drive is wrong.  From [The .NET 3.5 SP1 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en):

"Additionally, managed applications that are opened from network shares have the same behavior as native applications by running with full trust."

This change is long overdue: there is virtually no security benefit in preventing managed applications running from a network share, since a hacker could just as easily use an unmanaged application.