# Running a .NET application from a file share without code signing

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, security, clr

The .NET security model throws security errors whenever a .NET exe is run from a file share. The error does not appear when ran from a local drive. Does anyone know of a way around this without requiring the code to be signed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Using CasPol to Fully Trust a Share](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx)

more answers here:

[Why does my .NET application crash when run from a network drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148879/why-does-my-net-application-crash-when-run-from-a-network-drive)

Answer (score 2):

Use [caspol.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz(VS.80).aspx) to assign that file share enough permissions to run your program.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to build the application against .net 3.5 sp1 this version was removing this security setting.

Answer (score 1):

To get around this we ended up wrapping our .exe in a batch file. The batch file copied the .exe to the local drive and ran it from there. I'm sure there is a less hacky way though!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that .Net 3.5SP1 is installed on the machine which is running the software.  This version removes the security restriction on apps running from a file share.  It allows them to run at full trust vs. the previous model which put them in a restricted environment.

Here's a link to Vance's blog article on the subject

- http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .Net configuration wizard to loosen security for the specific Assembly and it's location, this in turn can be deployed through a group policy. You can also use caspol as earlier mentioned.

The other alternative is to use code access security. There is a brilliant MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0.aspx) explaining it.

The third alternative is using clickonce deployment, however this still creates a local instance of the assembly when executed.

Comment: For .NET 2.0 the configuration wizard is part of Visual Studio and can be found at "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\mscorcfg.msc"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Click Once deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4.aspx) to deploy your application from a file share.