# Trying to publish Visual Studio 2015 application just to local network

Tags: visual-studio-2015, publishing

I've made a small book-keeping application using wpf in Visual Studio 2015 just for my wife and I to use at home and I'm trying to publish it to a shared folder so that she can install it on her laptop but I don't really know what I'm doing.

I created a folder and shared it on the "Homegroup" and her laptop can view this folder. I'm now trying to publish the application to this folder so I've set the Publishing Folder location to this folder but I don't know what to set the Installation Folder to. What I've found online says I need to set it to an ftp or a website but surely this isn't necessary just to publish and user an application between 2 computers.

On a further note, I don't really want to install from disk as I'm probably going to be updating this application a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to check out this article to start from: Deploying a WPF Application (WPF) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa969776(v=vs.100).aspx 
I think in your case the xcopy case would be reasonable. But depending on your needs there are also other choices. Remember that each client has to have .Net-Framework installed to run the app.
HTH

Comment: Thank you for this. Tried it out and ended up copying the whole project folder over but I'll sort this. Managed to get the program to run on the laptop but I'm getting an error when trying to connect to the server set up on my PC. I guess this would be a new question though.

Comment: sometimes - depending on access level and things that you are doing you can copy the folder on a file share where every user has rights and then have just a link (short cut) to the exe file. If you encounter issues google for caspol and look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815740/running-a-net-application-from-a-file-share-without-code-signing

Comment: I can run the application absolutely fine now, I just run the .exe from the bin folder. I think my problem now is just connecting to my sqlserver on my main pc from the laptop

Comment: this can have a variety of issues. Wrong connection string, if windows authentication: user has no access to the db server etc. pipes are not activated. usually the event log of the client or server gives also hints in case something throws.