# run c# app from network share

Tags: c#

I'm new to c#, so please forgive me if i ask some entry level questions.

currently, I have a little windows form that have cancel button on it. I noticed that when i run it on local machine the cancel button works fine. but it gives me security exceptions when running from network location on xp machine.
the exception is telling me I cannot call unmanaged code etc ....
but my form only has one button and the code within eventhandler is: Application.Exit();

after googling around I found that I can make changes through mscorcfg.msc to give permission to intranet. this worked for me.

the other workaround I found is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288469(v=vs.71).aspx

however, this is a workaround for one machine only, what if I have a hundred machines????

so I assume there must be some other ways to deal with this problem, can anyone please help??

Comment: Pro tip: never "etc.." an exception message on SO. the exception messages are there for a reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my .NET application crash when run from a network drive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148879/why-does-my-net-application-crash-when-run-from-a-network-drive)

Comment: Did you notice that the link you found refers to .NET 1.1?

Comment: is it for .net 1.1?? i did not see anywhere that says for 1.1....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a feature of the .NET framework itself : Code Access Security.

By default, code on a network share will run with the security level of LocalIntranet that have  a lower level of privilege than if it is run on the local drive that is a "secure" location.

You can use the tool [caspool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get rid of this limitation and give trust execution to an executable also on a network location, so for example :

```
caspol -machine -addfulltrust program.exe
```

Comment: yes, i did find this tool caspol, but this is just for one machine, how about a hundred machines??   isn't there a way to do this within code??

Answer (score 3):

Update to a newer version of the framework. .Net no longer enforces this for network shares if you're running .Net 3.5 sp1 or later.